# Swift : TIC SSL Trust Error on loading self signed url in WebView

Tags: ios, webview, shift, self-signed

I was trying to load a self signed url inside Webview in a iOS app. Other urls are loading perfectly inside my webview.

I have added inside my info.plist file but getting error :-

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

And here is my full error :-

> 2019-01-08 12:26:52.386721+0530 Webview demo[761:27005] TIC SSL Trust
>   Error [2:0x282e90480]: 3:0
>
> 2019-01-08 12:26:52.405216+0530 Webview demo[761:27005]
>   NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed
>   (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9807)
>
> 2019-01-08 12:26:52.405283+0530 Webview demo[761:27005] Task
>   .<0> HTTP load failed (error
>   code: -1202 [3:-9807])
>
> 2019-01-08 12:26:52.405519+0530 Webview demo[761:27003]
>   NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1202

I am new to iOS please help me to understand and solve the problem.

Here is my ViewController :-

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let url = URL(string: "https://stackoverflow.com")

        if let unwrappedUrl = url{
            let request = URLRequest(url : unwrappedUrl)
            let session = URLSession.shared
            let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response , error) in
                if error == nil {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                         self.webView.loadRequest(request)
                    }
                }
            }

            task.resume()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

All you have to do is add some coding stuff instead of adding keys - value in Info.plist

> let serverTrustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy] = [
>                   "your site": .disableEvaluation
>               ]

Add above stuff in your session manager.

var disposition: URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition = .performDefaultHandling

> If you use alamofire them you can utilize the below method,

```
func urlSession(
        _ session: URLSession,
        task: URLSessionTask,
        didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge,
        completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void)
{
    var disposition: URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition = .performDefaultHandling
    var credential: URLCredential?

    if let taskDidReceiveChallenge = taskDidReceiveChallenge {
        (disposition, credential) = taskDidReceiveChallenge(session, task, challenge)
    } else if challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust {
        let host = challenge.protectionSpace.host

        if
            let serverTrustPolicy = session.serverTrustPolicyManager?.serverTrustPolicy(forHost: host),
            let serverTrust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust
        {
            if serverTrustPolicy.evaluate(serverTrust, forHost: host) {
                disposition = .useCredential
                credential = URLCredential(trust: serverTrust)
            } else {
                disposition = .cancelAuthenticationChallenge
            }
        }
    } else {
        if challenge.previousFailureCount > 0 {
            disposition = .rejectProtectionSpace
        } else {
            credential = self.credential ?? session.configuration.urlCredentialStorage?.defaultCredential(for: challenge.protectionSpace)

            if credential != nil {
                disposition = .useCredential
            }
        }
    }

    completionHandler(disposition, credential)
}
```

Comment: i am not using alomofire and  not sure where and how to add serverTrustPolicies. Please help